# jquery post array two dimensional

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, post, multidimensional-array

i have javascript array 2 dimensional == > records
i want to insert its data into database
i use jquery post by this code

```
    var data={"records" : records};
    $.post('new_puplic_insert.php',data,function(message){

        alert(message);
    });
```

in php file i want to prosess this array
example

```
 $dataarray=$_POST['records'];

 echo $dataarray[0][0];
```

but  return tags and not data in the array ?
what the correct way to pass the array 2 dimensional and recive it into php as it

Comment: You need to send it as JSON so that it identifies the object.. You cannot pass a 2d array directly.. Also  if you don't want to do this you can send it as a comma separated string to the server and build the 2d array again on the server side.. This may be fast but may eat up some of the processing time..

Answer (score 2):

The most simple and convenient way would be to encode array to JSON, pass it to PHP script and decode it in it.

Comment: array 2 dimention and i dont know what number of elemnts in it how can i encode array to JSON and decode it again